# Change Jaxb Generated File Encoding Per project (non maven) in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, encoding, ant, jaxb

I have the following issue:

I have a **non maven** project in `NetBeans` `8.2` which has `utf-8` encoding

(as shown with - right click on project properties).

In project I have created `JaxB` xml binding and so some sources are generated in `generated` folder.

However generated sources are not using `utf-8` and so I got

> error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8

if I try to compile.

If I change `netbeans_default_options` in (netbeans `etc\netbeans.conf`) so that it contains the line `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` the problem for the particular project is solved - everything compiles fine.

But this breaks the rest of my projects which are not `utf-8`.

I am looking for the solution that will not impact the rest of my projects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was adding the following

```
<arg value="-encoding"/>
<arg value="UTF-8"/>
```

into the ant script 
inside 
`xml_binding_build`

so that the resulting xjc would look like this

```
<xjc package="mypackage" destdir="build/generated/jaxbCache/mypackage" catalog="catalog.xml">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${src.dir}"/>
                <pathelement path="${jaxbwiz.xjcrun.classpath}"/>
            </classpath>
            <arg value="-xmlschema"/>
            <arg value="-encoding"/>
            <arg value="UTF-8"/>
            <schema file="xml-resources/jaxb/mypackage/mypackage.xsd"/>
            <depends file="xml-resources/jaxb/mypackage/mypackage.xsd"/>
            <produces dir="build/generated/jaxbCache/mypackage"/>
</xjc>
```

Ofcourse the `xml_binding_build.xml` is **generated** (automatically) and normally should not be edited by hand.

However this workatround is enough for me and it is better than converting every project to `utf-8`.